train an NN model independently for different input versions
I am working with PyTorch to train a neural network model, referred to as 'top_model.' Below, I have outlined my setup, followed by a detailed description of the challenge I am facing.
class torch_top_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(torch_top_model, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(25, 320)
        self.hidden_layer = nn.Linear(320, 64)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(64, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.input_layer(x))
        x = F.relu(self.hidden_layer(x))
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

top_model = torch_top_model()
top_model.train()

I have an input tensor of size (30, 25). For my input generation, I am splitting the 25 features into 5 groups of 5 features each.
model_inputs = torch.rand(30, 25)
model_labels = torch.randint(0, 10, (30,))
top_model_inputs = {}

for i in range(5):  # 4 groups (5 columns each)
    top_model_inputs[i] = model_inputs[:, i*5:(i+1)*5]

In the next step, I am generating versions of the input data where one group of features (corresponding to each key) is zeroed out while the others remain intact.
for key in range(1, len(top_model_inputs.keys())):
    temp = []
    for k in top_model_inputs:
      if k == key:
        temp.append(torch.zeros_like(top_model_inputs[k]))
      else:
        temp.append(top_model_inputs[k])
    temp_tensor = torch.cat(temp, dim=1)
    inputs[key] = temp_tensor

Next I start with the model training:
weights_and_biases = {i:top_model.state_dict() for i in range(1,5)}
optimizer = {i:torch.optim.Adam(top_model.parameters(), lr=0.01) for i in range(1,5)}
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
top_models = {i:copy.deepcopy(top_model) for i in range(1,5)}
epochs = 3

for i in range(epochs):
  for key in range(1, len(top_model_inputs.keys())):
    top_models[key].load_state_dict(weights_and_biases[key])
    outputs = top_models[key](inputs[key])
    loss = criterion(outputs, model_labels)
    optimizer[key].zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    if i == 2:
      w2 = weights_and_biases[2]['input_layer.weight'].clone().detach()
    optimizer[key].step()
    weights_and_biases[key] = top_models[key].state_dict()
    if i == 1:
      w1 = weights_and_biases[1]['input_layer.weight'].clone().detach()

      print("w1-w2: ", torch.norm(w1-w2))

My problem: For each versions of the input, as and when I run my algorithm through epochs, I only want the weights and biases of the corresponding inputs to be updated. For example in epoch1, I would like the model to update only weights_and_biases[1] for inputs[1], weights_and_biases[2] for inputs[2] and so on. In essence, I want the parameters (weights and biases) of the top_model to be updated separately for each input versions during each epoch, and then use those updated parameters in the next epoch.
Issue I am facing: The weights are being reused from weight_and_biases of other input versions. For example, weight_and_biases[1] is being used by inputs[2]. Therefore, I get a zero norm difference before and after updates from different input versions.
How to independently update the model parameters for different input versions across epochs? If this can be achieved without deep copying the model a number of times, that would be a more efficient solution.

I think you are confused about some very basic programming aspects here. Lets step through some things.
You create the model:
top_model = torch_top_model()

At this point you have one single model. Now you create this dict:
weights_and_biases = {i:top_model.state_dict() for i in range(1,5)}

At this point you still have one model. The entries in weights_and_biases all reference the same model state dict. The dict values are all pointers to the exact same object.
You create the optimizer dict
optimizer = {i:torch.optim.Adam(top_model.parameters(), lr=0.01) for i in range(1,5)}

At this point you still have one model. Each dict value is a different optimizer object, but they all reference the same weight objects.
You create the model copy dict
top_models = {i:copy.deepcopy(top_model) for i in range(1,5)}

Now you have created four new models. You have five models total - four in top_models plus the original model you cloned from.
Now your train loop
top_models[key].load_state_dict(weights_and_biases[key])
outputs = top_models[key](inputs[key])
loss = criterion(outputs, model_labels)
optimizer[key].zero_grad()
loss.backward()

If you understand the code you wrote, you can see clearly why this doesn't work. You use the model in top_models[key] with the optimizer optimizer[key]. top_models[key] points to one of the model copies you created. optimizer[key] points to the weights of the original model. They are referencing different objects. Loading the state dict via top_models[key].load_state_dict(weights_and_biases[key]) does not change this because it copies the data values from weights_and_biases[key] into the tensor objects in top_models[key].load_state_dict.
The reason you see no change in the weights is because you aren't updating them. You compute your loss with the weights in top_models[key], but your optimizer references the weights in the original top_model. There is no connection between the two. If you actually inspect a gradient value of a parameter in the optimizer (optimizer[key].param_groups[0]['params'][0].grad) you will find it is None because no gradient is being computed. The parameters in the optimizer are unrelated to the parameters you use to calculate your loss.
I think you are also confused about what you are trying to accomplish. When you say I would like the model to update only weights_and_biases[1] for inputs[1], weights_and_biases[2] for inputs[2], it implies you want to train separate models on the different inputs. When you say If this can be achieved without deep copying the model, it implies you want a single model.
You can train a single model on all versions of the input, or you can train separate instances of the model on the separate inputs.

Thanks for the detailed answer! Based on your response, I was able to successfully train separate copies of the model on separate inputs. Since the neural network structure of the different models I want to train is the same, I was hoping to achieve this with just a single copy of the model. My plan is to initialize the inputs, weights, and biases of the neural network with the latest values for the ith model, perform a single forward and backward pass, and then update the stored weights and biases for that model. I would then repeat this process for each model. Is this feasible?

I don't know what you mean by "a single copy of the model". You have multiple copies. The weights are the model. The nn.Module class is just a container for the weights. In a technical sense yes you can have multiple sets of weights that you swap in/out of the same model object, but there is no benefit to doing this
